# Loop contract addresses with dynamic Interface Name

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I have multiple contract's addresses and their respective interfaces.

Name of contracts are:

```
 1. ContractA_v1
 2. ContractA_v2
```

Name of interfaces are:

```
 1. IContractA_v1
 2. IContractA_v2
```

`allConractAddresses` holds the addresses of my 2 contracts;

```
address [] allConractAddresses;
uint256 lastIndex = allConractAddresses.length - 1;
        while (lastIndex >= 0) {
            address cAddress = allConractAddresses[lastIndex];
            
            versionedSC = IContractA_v1(cAddress);

            //rest code here
            
            lastIndex--;
        }
```

My concern is how can I make the line `versionedSC = IContractA_v1(cAddress);` dynamic with **interface** name?

Answer (score 0):

If the "rest code" works for every interface it means that these contracts shares a common subset of methods with the same signatures.
You could simply create an interface, this is the idea:

```
interface ICommon {
    function foo();
    function bar();
}

interface IContract1 is ICommon {
    function exclusiveMethod1();
}


interface IContract2 is ICommon {
    function exclusiveMethod2();
}
```

(I haven't tried this code, it's only to grasp the idea)

This way that line simply become `versionedSC = ICommon(cAddress);`.
Note that you may not even need the `IContract<i>` declarations in your contract if you always call only the common methods.

Comment: If I do versionedSC = ICommon(cAddress); then how can I execute exclusiveMethod1() method from IContract1?

Comment: You can't and I don't understand why you would, if the "rest code here" part works for every contract in `allContractAddresses` this means that in that part only the common methods (`foo()` and `bar()`) are called.

If the "rest code here" part calls different methods on different contracts it must use conditionals to distinguish them and therefore you can simply load the different addresses using different interfaces. However if you have a finite number of interfaces you can always transform your loop in a long sequence of instructions.

Comment: That's the main problem I have. I am not sure over time how many interfaces there are going to be and for that how many if else conditions do I have to implement for picking up the interfaces. Thats the reason I want to have the             versionedSC = IContractA_v1(cAddress); dynamic